# How to solve this Indefinite Integral step by step?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Integrate

$$ 
\int
\frac{\sqrt{(x^2+1)^5}}{x^6}
\; dx 
$$
 Trying this question but unable to solve. 
Wolfram does it with hyperbolic substitution, I have been asked to solve this integral without hyperbolic substitution.

Comment: Please use MathJax syntax in order for the question to be more clear!

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: Let $x = \tan u$ perhaps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\tan u$ therefore $$\int
\frac{\sqrt{(x^2+1)^5}}{x^6}
\; dx 
=\int\dfrac{1}{\cos^7 u}\dfrac{\cos^6 u}{\sin^6 u}du=\int\dfrac{\cos udu}{\sin^6 u(1-\sin^2 u)}$$let $w=\sin u$ therefore $$\int\dfrac{\cos udu}{\sin^6 u(1-\sin^2 u)}=\int\dfrac{dw}{w^6(1-w^2)}=\int\dfrac{0.5}{1-w}+\dfrac{0.5}{1+w}+\dfrac{1}{w^6}+\dfrac{1}{w^4}+\dfrac{1}{w^2}dw\\=0.5\ln|\dfrac{w+1}{w-1}|-\dfrac{1}{5w^5}-\dfrac{1}{3w^3}-\dfrac{1}{w}+C$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sqrt{(x^{2}+1)^{5}}}{x^{6}} = \frac{1}{x}\frac{\sqrt{(x^{2}+1)^{5}}}{x^{5}} = \frac{1}{x}\sqrt{\frac{(x^{2}+1)^{5}}{x^{10}}} = \frac{1}{x}\sqrt{\left(\frac{x^{2}+1}{x^{2}}\right)^{5}} = \frac{1}{x}\sqrt{\left(1 + \frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)^{5}}
\end{align*}

Comment: Further what is the step ?

Comment: Make the substitution $1/x = \tan(\theta)$.